# Bibliography on Hecke characters

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, zeta-functions, hecke-characters

Do you know of any book, lecture note or survey article that deals in detail with Grössencharaktere and Hecke characters, this is, in both "ideal" and "idèle" interpretations?

With "in detail" I mean something like Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory". Usually, what I find is the definition and a few properties, sometimes without proofs or references.

Comment: There are a lot of examples of Hecke characters in Günter Köhler, _Eta Products and Theta Series Identities_, which may be what you are looking for, but no proofs.

Comment: Dear @Somos. Thank you very much for the reference. That's actually a nice book.